# NSArray componentsJoinedByString Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have written a method (shown below). The project is compiled using ARC, but the file the method is in has to be compiled with the -fno-objc-arc switch because of a third party library dependency.

The leak inspector is telling me that there is a leak on

```
return [fragments componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

I can't see it - could I ask for another pair of eyes to point out the error of my ways?

Many thanks

```
-(NSString *)trimAndTidy:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSCharacterSet *nsc = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r\n \t"];
    NSString *fragment;
    NSMutableArray *fragments = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
    do
    {
        if ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:nsc intoString:&fragment])
            [fragments addObject:fragment];
    }
    while (![scanner isAtEnd]);
    return [fragments componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
}
```

Comment: There's no leak in the code you've posted. What's the exact message from the debugging tool you're using?

Comment: The code fragment looks good - everything is autoreleased, including the result. How do you use `trimAndTidy`?

Comment: As a guess, and only a guess, I would say it might be aString. `[x trimAndTidy:[[NSString alloc] init]]` might claim a leak on that line, because it's the last point where aString is in scope.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Typical call looks like this `_name = [self trimAndTidy aName];`

Comment: That would be a leak, yeah. What does the calling code look like?

Comment: @drew Assuming that the call `_name = [self trimAndTidy:aName]` is **not** in an ARC module, you should release `_name` before making an assignment, or access `_name` through a `retain` property, assuming there is one (i.e. `self.name = [self trimAndTidy:aName]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leak inspector tells you *where a leak was allocated* and not *where the leak was caused*.

To find the cause, you have to find the extra `retain` or missing `release` call.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance - an elementary error - I forgot all about creating a `dealloc` method which of course is required because this file is compiled without ARC.  How quickly one forgets?!!!